# iOS: Distribute beta apps without UDID

Tags: ios, udid, developer-program

My team is developing an iOS app, which is still on the Beta phase.

When we show the app to potential partners, we use [testflight](https://www.testflightapp.com/dashboard/) to share the app with them. Alas, testflight requires the user's UDID which is obtainable only through iTunes on a Mac, which is cumbersome. We would like to be able to email users with app invites using their email address only.

**Can we use the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/gettingstarted/) to let potential partners try the app using their email address only, without UDIDs involved?**

Comment: yes.. without UDID you can use enterprise account to send build file to testers globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with an iOS Developer Enterprise Program membership you are able to distribute your app to devices without needing any device information.

However, now that TestFlight is incorporated in all paid developer accounts, that's much preferable to solve the problem of managing test users than upping your account to enterprise.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an authoritative link to establish your answer?

Comment: @Adam Personal experience ;) Documentation is behind membership login though. If you want an example, the [SE iOS beta app](https://mobile.stackexchange.com/ios) is distributed with Enterprise and doesn't require UDID or specific provisioning profiles. An [iTunes manifest property list](https://mobile.stackexchange.com/ios/ios.plist) is used to distribute a signed .ipa.

Answer (score 2):

TestFlight do not require UDIDs any more. You can distribute apps with TestFlight without having the UDIDs of all those test devices. Just invite the testers by providing their email addresses. They will be able to join you. You need an Apple developer account (99 USD per year) to use TestFlight.

And yes, with Developer Enterprise Program (299 USD per year), you can also distribute enterprise apps. You can distribute such apps to the users directly by just providing the Email address, and have them installed on the devices without any limits. Enterprise account does not require UDIDs. Know more about TestFlight, Developer Enterprise account and other options at [Enterprise App Distribution - Hexnode blogs](https://www.hexnode.com/blogs/enterprise-app-distribution/)

Answer (score 0):

Also check out Diawi it might be an alternative but still "official" way https://www.diawi.com/

> Over-the-air installation of apps on iOS is based on tools and features provided officially by Apple: itms-service and a valid manifest file providing information on the app.

Comment: diawi is a terrific tool, but you must have entered the user's UDID into the Apple Dev account and downloaded the updated provisioning profile into XCode before you can distribute a build.